# Callouts gets shifted in different screens

Tags: highcharts

Im trying to implement callouts for our graphs but noticed the callout points gets shifted for different screen sizes.

Here is the correct one:-

[image]

Wrong one(bigger screen size)

[image]

This is how I calculate the x_axis and y_axis.. Sometimes the points sits on other points, so I add some values(x_axis_point & y_axis_point) to shift the position.

```
x_axis = (point.plotX + chart.plotLeft ) + parseInt(x_axis_position)
y_axis = (point.plotY + chart.plotTop ) - parseInt(y_axis_position)
```

Working fiddle..The callout box should be displayed at the same position irrespective of different screen size.

https://jsfiddle.net/cucjw7xc/5/

new fiddle: line displacement

```
https://jsfiddle.net/cucjw7xc/11/
```

Comment: Paste your code here or recreate the issue live (jsfiddle/codenpen/etc.) Otherwise, it is guessing what you are doing. If you want the callout to be position in a spefic axis value you should use [Axis.toPixels()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.toPixels) for calculatiion.

Comment: @morganfree: Added the jsfiddle.

Comment: So you want the callout to be in a fixed position in terms of axis values? If so, you need to use axis.toPixels for calculate x/y of the callout. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cucjw7xc/7/) - the callout will be drawn at 4 and 60 in terms of axis scale.

Comment: @morganfree: I have added another fiddle to show where I have a issue..The box looks good but when I draw a line it gets displaced very badly based on the screen size.